# Kubernetes menu not showing in docker desktop (Mac)

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop, apple-silicon

**Problem**

I have multiple k8s cluster on the cloud and I wanted to use docker desktop UI to change the context. The problem is, my docker desktop panel not showing "Kubernetes" menu.

**What I have tried**

- run `kubectl config get-contexts` and it shows 3 contexts. One is **docker-desktop** and the other two are my contexts.
- Enable kubernetes and show system containers in docker desktop preference.

**Current device**

- Macbook Pro (Apple Silicon - M1)
- Docker desktop v3.3.1
- Kubernetes v1.19.7 (from docker desktop)

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e16fD.png)

[Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlyum.png)

Answer (score 2):

**ENABLING KUBERNETES IN DOCKER DESKTOP**

- Assuming Docker Desktop is already installed on your computer, you
  can start the Kubernetes cluster by clicking the whale icon in the
  system tray and opening the Settings dialog box.
- Click the Kubernetes tab(on the left-hand side) and make sure the
  `Enable Kubernetes` checkbox is selected. The components that make up
  the Control Plane run as Docker containers, but they aren’t displayed
  in the list of running containers when you invoke the docker ps
  command. To display them, select the Show system containers checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but still happening. I had to give access to my `~/.kube/config` to get docker to enable it to update the file with the docker-desktop context and make sure you don't already have a docker-desktop context in there.